# Does C++ have a standard way to do a tristate comparison of two std::sets, vectors, etc?

Tags: c++, comparison, std

Is there an equivalent to [std::string::compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) for other std types, such as std::set? I'm looking for a built-in algorithm that can do the comparison just once and give me something like -1, 0, 1 for less than, equal, greater than, respectively.

Comment: What would it mean for a set/vector to be greater than another one?

Comment: If you're patient you will "soon" get [three-way comparison](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Three-way_comparison). Some compilers might already have it implemented.

Comment: @Rakete1111: `set` and `vector` already have `<` with lexical order (assuming `<` is valid for `T`).

Comment: Is there the option to consider subtraction? Then you only have to look at the sign and zero flags. `a<b => a-b<0`, `a=b => a-b=0`, and `a>b => a-b>0`... One operation and then only checking flags. (That's how I would implement is in assembly)

Comment: @JHBonarius No. But the accepted solution from Benjamin works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no single algorithm which will do that. But you can compose such a function with the use of `std::mismatch`.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
int compare(T1 const& A, T2 const& B)
{
    // find the first element which differs
    auto mismatchPoint =
        std::mismatch(std::begin(A), std::end(A), std::begin(B), std::end(B));

    if (mismatchPoint.first == std::end(A)) {

        // no elements differ
        if (mismatchPoint.second == std::end(B))
            return 0;

        // A ends before B, so A < B
        return -1;
    } else if (mismatchPoint.second == std::end(B) {
        // B ends before A, so B < A
        return 1;
    } else {

        // compare the first different element
        if (*mismatchPoint.first < *mismatchPoint.second)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Require `==` and `<`.

Comment: @Jarod42 It requires those operators on the single point of data inside the data structures, not on the data structures themselves. Major performance difference.

Comment: @srm: I mean that some algorithms only require `<`, and use `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` instead of `a == b`. (in the same way `>` might not exist even if `<` exists (and it is even generally the case with custom class implementing `operator <`)).

Answer (score 1):

You might write (using only `operator <`):

```
template <typename T>
int compare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
    if (lhs < rhs) return -1;
    else if (rhs < lhs) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm specifically trying to avoid the performance problem of doing both comparisons.

Comment: If you limit yourself to only `operator <` and no `operator ==`, then worst complexity is good.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic three way comparison function in the standard library, so you will need to implement it yourself. It's trivial to implement it using the less-than operator.

There are also no standard algorithms that use a "three-way comparison" function (except those inherited from C that cannot be used with containers anyway).

There is a [proposal](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r0.pdf) to add a new operator to the standard that would implement such comparison.

Answer (score 0):

C++2a introduces spaceship operator (`<=>`) which does mostly that. (See http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r0.pdf)

Before that, you have to rely on other ways as proposed answers.